# error mysqli de conexión a mi base de datos en el servidor?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, php7

tengo problemas con esta conexión mysql, siempre lo he usado de esta manera a manera de local y ahora que esta en el servidor no me funciona, deseo sugerencias y aportes que me ayuden a corregir el error.

```
class Conexion {

//PARA USAR SERVIDOR LOCAL
/* private $servername = "localhost";
  private $username = "root";
  private $password = "";
  private $bd="transparenta";
  private $conn; */


private $servername = "posta.transparenta-bi.com";
private $username = "transpar_user_db";
private $password = "transparenta1234";
private $bd = "transpar_proyectoTransparenta";
private $conn;

function openConexion() {
    $this->conn= new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->bd);
    return $this->conn;
}

function closeConexion() {
    $this->conn->close();
}
```

}

estos son los siguientes errores que aparecen en mi pantalla de navegador.

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\conexion\conexion.php on line 26

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\conexion\conexion.php on line 26
```

Comment: Hola Gean, como recomendación te sugiero no publicar datos reales como claves, nombres de usuario, entre otras ya que puede existir gente malintencionada. Continuando con tu consulta: Es necesario que nos puedas brindar un poco más de información ¿la web está alojada en un servidor con Cpanel o en un VPS? normalmente las rutas en servidores web sigue siendo locahost, ingresa a phpmyadmin y la url que te aparezca esa debe ser la del servidor.

Comment: esta en un servidor con cpanel , siempre he usado esta conexión para todos mis proyectos web, en esta ocación es un servidor nuevo y no me acepta esta conexión , quisiera que me aporten una solución para continuar con mi proyecto.

Comment: ya intentaste colocando http://.../ al host?

Comment: Si el proyecto está alojado en el mismo servidor _o hosting_ que la base de datos, prueba usando `private $servername = "localhost";`

Comment: Si el servidor es nuevo y antes funcionaba. Tiene toda la pinta de ser algo del lado del servidor. Consulta a tu Proveedor y muestrale los errores. Posiblemente sea un tema de configuración.